# How <script> tag forces MutationObserver to run early in Declarative Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, mutation-observers

I have found [this](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/shadow-dom/declarative/innerhtml-before-closing-tag.tentative.html) particular test in WPT tests:

```html
<script>
function myObserver(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    for (let n of mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (n.id === 'shadow') {
        n.innerHTML = "<span id=replaced>This should be in &lt;div>'s shadow root</span>";
      }
    }
  }
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(myObserver);
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>

<div id=host>
  <template id=shadow shadowroot=open>
    <span id=toreplace>This should get removed</span>
    <script></script> <!-- Ensure observer runs -->
  </template>
</div>
```

Now the questions is about `<script></script> <!-- Ensure observer runs -->` -> how does this line of code ensures that observer runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#run-a-classic-script) does trigger the [cleanup after running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script) steps, which itself does force a [microtask-checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint) where the observer's notifications will be dispatched.
My guess is that they use it here to force these mutation notifications before the `<template>` tag is closed, as is hinted by the test's name "*innerHTML before closing tag*".

However if my guess is correct, I believe this code is actually buggy:
All browsers don't run the script if the `<script>` tag is completely empty, In Firefox it needs to have at least some text content for it to run all these steps and thus to force the microtask-checkpoint. Even a space character will do, but it's necessary, as demonstrated in below snippets:

Using a completely empty `<script></script>`, we see in Firefox that the observer runs when the whole element has already been parsed.

```html
<script>
function myObserver(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    for (let n of mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (n.id === 'parent') {
        console.log([...n.children].map(el => el.outerHTML));
      }
    }
  }
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(myObserver);
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>

<div id=parent>
  <span id=child>This should be in the log.</span>
  <script></script><!-- forces the observer to run -->
  <span id=sibling>This should not be in the log</span>
</div>
```

Running the same snippet with only a space character included in the `<script> </script>`, we see that the observer runs right after the `<script>` has been parsed, and before the "sibling" `<span>` has.

```html
<script>
function myObserver(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    for (let n of mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (n.id === 'parent') {
        console.log([...n.children].map(el => el.outerHTML));
      }
    }
  }
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(myObserver);
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>

<div id=parent>
  <span id=child>This should be in the log.</span>
  <script> </script><!-- forces the observer to run -->
  <span id=sibling>This should not be in the log</span>
</div>
```

I opened [an issue on WPT](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/issues/35393) for Mason Freed or anyone else there to have a look and confirm my hypothesis, and maybe fix these tests if needed.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. So it seems I was looking for an answer in the wrong places (MutationObserver and Shadow DOM spec). I can't wait for the explanation/confirmation in the GH issue. Until then I will let this question to be "open"

Comment: Fair enough, but don't hold your breath until then ;-) The tests are marked as `.tentative` which means the behavior they are testing hasn't been standardized yet and thus they may not see any real hurry in fixing these.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising the issue! I agree with your analysis, and I posted also on your [WPT issue](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/issues/35393). Per [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script), all classic scripts, regardless of whether they're empty, should run microtasks. Unless I missed something, this seems like a bug in Gecko.

Quick comment also - these are definitely still .tentative tests, since Gecko and WebKit are waiting for definitive evidence that Declarative Shadow DOM is "a good thing". My [pull request to add it](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/pull/892) to the spec is still awaiting the support of other implementers.

Comment: Fingers crossed for shipping DSD to other browsers soon! Fantastic work on the spec :) Keep it up