# With the same code, why are the execution results inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I have an HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./script1.js"></script>
<script src="./script2.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log('inline-111')
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inline-setTimeout-111')
    }, 0);
</script>
<script>
   console.log('inline-222')
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inline-setTimeout-222')
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inline-setTimeout-333')
    }, 0);
    new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('inline-Promise1')
      resolve()
    })
      .then(function () {
        console.log('inline-promise2')
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log('inline-promise3')
      })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first script tag code.

```
console.log("external-111");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout-external-111");
}, 0);
```

The second script tag code.

```
console.log("external-222");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout-external-222");
}, 0);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("setTimeout-external-333");
  }, 0);
  
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("external-Promise1");
  resolve();
})
  .then(function () {
    console.log("external-promise2");
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("external-promise3");
  });
```

When running in Google Chrome(Chrome119.0.6045.200), the result is

```
external-111
setTimeout-external-111
external-222
external-Promise1
external-promise2
external-promise3
inline-111
inline-222
inline-Promise1
inline-promise2
inline-promise3
setTimeout-external-222
setTimeout-external-333
inline-setTimeout-111
inline-setTimeout-222
inline-setTimeout-333
```

When running in Firefox(121.0.1), the result is

```
external-111 
external-222  
external-Promise1
external-promise2
external-promise3
inline-111
inline-222
inline-Promise1
inline-promise2
inline-promise3
setTimeout-external-111
setTimeout-external-222
setTimeout-external-333
inline-setTimeout-111
inline-setTimeout-222
inline-setTimeout-333
```

Why is the output on the second line inconsistent?
Is there any kind-hearted friend who can try to explain?

At first, I wanted to understand how the event loop would run when multiple scripts were mixed in the browser. But the two running results caused confusion.

Comment: setTimeouts only guarantee that they'll run _after_ the set delay.

Comment: I really don't understand the fascination with questions like this. The details are interesting in some edge cases, but to me it would be completely crazy to architect client-side code to expect particular behaviors from browsers evaluating such code. With timeouts in particular, it's easy enough to impose your own ordering by using incremented delay values.

Comment: @Pointy why don't you ignore the event-loop tag then? I already told you if memory serves well, but what's the point of you repeating ad nauseam that you don't see the point of such questions? There is a very valid point in trying to understand why a code works differently in 2 different environments.

Comment: It is indeed very likely that it will not be helpful for normal construction of the project. But I still want to try to understand why it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanations is that the external scripts took a different amount of time to load. Notice this does not even depend on the browser, but will also differ between multiple loads of the page in the same browser.

If the second external script takes a longer time to load, the timeout scheduled in the first script may be run before the script executes. If it takes a shorter time to load, the timeout will run after the script executes (but still before the timeout - with the same millisecond value - scheduled by the second script).

Comment: Right, I misread their code yesterday and since all the timeouts are scheduled from the page loading, the difference in task prioritization doesn't matter here. Might be noted, since they also were trying to do stuff with Promises, that a when the parser meets an opening `<script>` tag, it will run a microtask checkpoint, (this is observable for instance [with a MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73283986/how-script-tag-forces-mutationobserver-to-run-early-in-declarative-shadow-dom))

Comment: Just one more point, I'm not entirely sure to understand your last sentence between parentheses. The millisecond value unfortunately doesn't matter much (contrarily to what the comments under the question were suggesting), if the (classic) script takes longer to load than the set timeout, it will run even before a smaller timeout set after (or inside) the external script. The clock keeps running even when the HTML parser is blocked. https://jsfiddle.net/mwskLz7a/ (be sure to prevent HTTP cache when running the snippet)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If it is when the browser first loads and executes the external link code, you are right. But if it is no longer the first time to load and all external link codes are cached in memory, the situation described above will occur. I tried to add multiple copies of the same external link tag code and found that the output results between the two browsers were inconsistent only in the first external link code. So, does Google Chrome have some priority in executing the first external link code?

Comment: @Kaiido Isn't the microtask checkpoint run when the closing `</script>` tag is met, i.e. right after the script's execution, not when an opening `<script>` tag is met?

Comment: @Kaiido Re the last paragraph, I meant that `setTimeout(() => { console.log('inline-setTimeout-111') }, 0);` (in the first script) is called before `setTimeout(() => { cnsole.log('inline-setTimeout-222') }, 0);` is called (in the second script), and therefore the two callbacks will always be executed in that order as well.

Comment: @Daguai It might just load the script faster. Or start fetching the second script sooner (even before the first is finished). It really doesn't matter, this behaviour might change at any point in time due to changes in the implementation.

Comment: *Isn't the microtask checkpoint run when the closing </script> tag is met, i.e. right after the script's execution,* It's indeed on the end tag, you're right, but [before the script execution](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inhead:~:text=reprocess%20the%20token.-,An%20end%20tag%20whose%20tag%20name%20is%20%22script%22,-If%20the%20active), and then again after the script execution in *Clean up after running script*

Comment: As for the last paragraph, that would then be true only for `0` timeouts, or first is smaller than second, though. I think it's actually an important point with that question since even experimented developers seem to get it wrong. I guess people assume that since the parser is blocked the event loop and JS are too.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, thanks, i didn't know about the one *before* the script execution!

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, if the first `setTimeout` has a higher duration than the second `setTimeout`, the order of callback executions would be indeterminate. I thought it was obvious but it's good to point out regardless.